# how to change frame layout height and width programatically?

Tags: android-layout

I am new to android.

I face one problem that is i am adding frame layout to my application the code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout1">
        <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is i want to change the frame layout height in different screen orientations

the sample code is

```
    wm = (WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            Log.v("height","height"+wm.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());

            if(wm.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() <= 427)
             {
                 Log.v("height","111");


((FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1)).setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
         }
        else
        {
            ((FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1)).setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        }
```

But it gives force close ,

if any one has idea please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to build a custom view and override the onLayout and onMeasure functions. In the onLayout function you can override the width and the height. See the example LabelView.java class [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/LabelView.html).

Answer (score 3):

You have to use LinearLayout.LayoutParams (int width, int height, float weight)

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layPra = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height,mWeight);
layPra .gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM;
frameLayout .setLayoutParams(layPra );
```